# How to match line start and ending with specific text

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm having a hard time with this regex. I'm trying to match the amount in the line starting with "`Zahlbetrag`" which ends with "`CHF`".

The text to search is:

```
Zwischentotal   0,00          13,24               906,79 CHF
Zahlbetrag      0,00          13,25               906,80 CHF
```

My regex so far:

```
(?<=Zahlbetrag)(?:.*?)((\d+,\d{2})(?=([\s]*)CHF))
```

The result of this is currently (tested with https://regex101.com/):

```
Match 1:       0,00          13,25               906,80
Group 1: 906,80
Group 2: 906,80
Group 3:
```

But I need the first match to be:

```
Match 1: 906,80
```

It should only include the last number, not the full line. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You already have it, it is in capture group 2, or change it a bit to just capture group 1 `Zahlbetrag\b.*?\b(\d+,\d{2})\s*CHF\b` See https://regex101.com/r/KNRTCs/1 (the group 1 value is highlighted in green)

Comment: You want `Zahlbetrag.*?\K\d+,\d{2}(?=\s*CHF)`, right? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Li0q9T/1). But this is a PCRE/Onigmo only regex.

Comment: @the-fourth-bird thank you for your help - but unfortunately, this is not working for me, since I cannot access group1 - the software is only outputting the first match. Wiktor's solution is giving me the output I needed. So thank you both of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Zahlbetrag.*?\K\d+,\d{2}(?=\s*CHF)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Li0q9T/1). *Details*:

- `Zahlbetrag` - a literal string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?=\s*CHF)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and then `CHF`.

Answer (score -1):

```
pattern = r"([\d,]*) CHF$"

st = "Zahlbetrag      0,00          13,25               906,80 CHF"

result = re.search(pattern, st)

result[1]= '906,80'
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.
Also, formatting and grammar are important on SO. See "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"